# How can we convert a Time stamp ' 2023-04-19 06:29:08' which is a Object data type to Float Datatype

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp, data-manipulation

My data

```
Time stamp                    Data
04-19-2023 06:29:08           13.26
04-19-2023 09:37:06           29.07
04-19-2023 16:28:18           34.98
04-19-2023 19:09:31           12.06
```

Need to convert a Time stamp ' 2023-04-19 06:29:08' which is a Object data type to Float Datatype.Need to plot a box plot for the data.
I used to customize the timestamp from excel and moved to jupyter notebook where it showed the data type as float but getting the value in exponential format. How can i get the actual time stamp value as a float data type.
somewhere i sawed the data is converted into below format.. How it can be converted.
If we are unable to convert the timestamp to float how can we build a model for prediction using timestamp.?

Can some one help me to resolve this issue.

Tried to change in excel .. getting values in exponential which is not expected.
Tried the reg to format the data to float it didnt worked for timestamp

Comment: Post any code at all.